# How to use jquery delegate method?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hi I have a problem...

I have to show all the results generated from a mysql query using php, in the end I generate a "block" that shortened is like this:

```
<div class="resultado">

    <div class="titulo_articulo">

        <h2>Título del artículo</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="detalles_articulo">    

        <div class="datos_articulo">    

            <div class="encabezado_autores">
                <img src="images/gente.png"><span> AUTORES</span>
            </div>

            <div class="autores_instituciones">
                <li>Daniel OC - UTPL</li>
                <li>Francisco V - UTPL</li>
            </div>      

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Sometimes searches return 5 results, so that code is inserted 5 times considering the different values (I'm not supposed to use antyhing that is not .hide() and .slide, so that's why I get a looot of code)...

I have a line generated for each result:
    Mostrar resultado n1

That line is clicked and the following event is called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".resultado").hide(); 

        $('.mostrar').click(function(e){
            $(".resultado").slideToggle();          
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Ok, so what do I do to use only once that event? Otherwise I have to give 5 different ids and place the script 5 times...

Comment: I don't see class `.mostrar` anywhere ...

Comment: "*I have a line generated for each result: Mostrar resultado n1*"...what does the html for that look like? And are those lines in the same order as their corresponding results above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to make it work:

Created a div called resultado with the a href inside of it, it has the class mostrar, the block that i posted has the class datos, this is the resulting script that made it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".datos").hide();

        $('.resultado').delegate('.mostrar','click',function(event){

          $(this).parent().find(".datos").slideToggle();

        }); 
    });
</script>
```

HTML ended up like this

```
<div class="resultado">

    <a class="mostrar" href="#">Mostrar/Ocultar resultado 1</a>

    <div class="datos">

        <div class="titulo_articulo">

            <h2>Título del artículo</h2>

        </div>

        <div class="detalles_articulo">    

            <div class="datos_articulo">    

                <div class="encabezado_autores">

                    <img src="images/gente.png"><span> AUTORES</span>

                </div>

                <div class="autores_instituciones">

                    <li>Daniel OC - UTPL</li>
                    <li>Francisco V - UTPL</li>

                </div>      

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must assign an `ID` for usability, classes are not very OK when it comes to this part of things:

```
<div class="mostrar" id="mostrarn1">Click me to show/hide result 1</div>
<div class="resultado" id="mostrarn1result">
    <div class="titulo_articulo">
        <h2>Título del artículo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="detalles_articulo">    
        <div class="datos_articulo">    
            <div class="encabezado_autores">
                <img src="images/gente.png"><span> AUTORES</span>
            </div>
            <div class="autores_instituciones">
                <li>Daniel OC - UTPL</li>
                <li>Francisco V - UTPL</li>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mostrar" id="mostrarn2">Click me to show/hide result 2</div>
<div class="resultado" id="mostrarn2result">
    <div class="titulo_articulo">
        <h2>Título del artículo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="detalles_articulo">    
        <div class="datos_articulo">    
            <div class="encabezado_autores">
                <img src="images/gente.png"><span> AUTORES</span>
            </div>
            <div class="autores_instituciones">
                <li>Daniel OC - UTPL</li>
                <li>Francisco V - UTPL</li>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.resultado').hide();
    $('.mostrar').click(function(e){
        var divId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+divId+'result').slideToggle();       
    }); ​
</script>
```

Comment: maybe.. the answer is probably relative to `$(this)`. But hard to figure out without the whole thing.

Comment: That code is repeated 5 times but with different values, i have to get the event thing to be placed only once and not 5 times...

Comment: I don't think you are providing the full code. If you hide `resultado` it will not show anything.

Comment: Well after you do the mysql query you get:
-Click me to show/hide result 1
-Click me to show/hide result 2

if I clicked one it will show that block, if i click the link again it will hide it...

I just dont want to place the script 5 times, I want one to work with the 5 divs...

Comment: Updated my answer, you should use id's

Answer (score 0):

With html looking something like this:

```
<div class="resultado">
...
</div>
<div class="resultado">
...
</div>
<div class="resultado">
...
</div>
<span class='mostrar' > Mostrar result 1</span>
<span class='mostrar' > Mostrar result 2</span>
<span class='mostrar' > Mostrar result 3</span>
```

You could accomplish the desired functionality by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".resultado").hide(); 

    $('.mostrar').click(function(e){
        var i = $(this).index('.mostrar');
        $(".resultado").eq(i).slideToggle();          
    }); 
});
```

This relies on the show result links being in the same order as the result blocks in the html.